# Why does FileInputStream read method in java return a int, not a short?

Tags: java

I aware that byte is not a proper type enough to contain result of read method.
So, read method returns int type value.
But i think a short type is more efficient type than int.
It could contain the value of range -256~ 255.
Why does read method return int, not short?

Comment: Nobody really uses `short`s...

Comment: "But i think a short type is more efficient type than int." - In what context? For a method call, with the value being stored in a local variable afterwards (which may well end up being a register) I would be surprised to see any significant difference.

Comment: i really want to know short is more efficient type than int, is that right?

Comment: First off, I feel the `java.io` package, in general, is not a well-written API. Secondly, in regards to short vs. int efficiency, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531235/in-java-is-it-more-efficient-to-use-byte-or-short-instead-of-int-and-float-inst

Comment: @crazy_rudy Actually, internally, `short` is represented the same as `int` in the Oracle JVM (it could be more efficient in other VMs, because it's implementation dependant, but in practice, `short` and `int` are always the same). The only place where you should consider `short` is when creating a huge `short[]` array. In that case, the VMs generally use the real two-byte shorts instead of `int`s internally (and that saves space).

Comment: Also note that File, FileInputStream etc. are legacy APIs. It's recommended to use the new NIO.2 File API if possible.

Comment: @Puce Some people need to stay backwards compatible with 1.6 or even 1.5 Heck, there are commercial solutions out there that require certain patchlevels of 1.3 or 1.4

Comment: @Ingo I know, that's why I wrote "if possible". I don't think everybody is aware of this new API and people are quite used to the old File API.

Comment: @Puce No, it isn't recommended. Don't post misinformation here.

Comment: @EJP Well, the official Java tutorial from Oracle updated the File tutorial and only uses the new NIO.2 File API. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html 
And I read that there are issues with the current java.io.File which are fixed with new API. So indeed like e.g. java.util.Date and soon java.util.Calendar, java.io.File although not deprecated is a legacy API.

Comment: @EJP here some further readings: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-139843.html#1

Comment: @EJP And yes, even the Java tutorial calls it "legacy code": http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/legacy.html

Comment: @Puce The 'File' class is referred to as 'legacy' in your citations, not the entire java.io package.

Comment: @EJP I never said the entire java.io package, but the FileXyStream/Reader/Writer also belong to the legacy API, AFAIK, since it's recommended to use `java.nio.file.Files` now to create streams/ reader/ writers etc. for files now from `Path` objects.

Comment: @Puce That's not stated in your links. The inference is yours alone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Java documentation on primitive types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) suggests that `short`s should be used instead of `int`s to "save memory in large arrays":

> **`short`:** The `short` data type is a 16-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -32,768 and a maximum value of 32,767 (inclusive). As with `byte`, the same guidelines apply: you can use a `short` to save memory in large arrays, in situations where the memory savings actually matters.

Since in this situation memory savings do not actually matter, using `int` is a more consistent choice.

Comment: +1 The JVM uses a 32-bit "slot" for byte, char, short and int as a return value.

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons:

- You can easily read more than 32 KB worth of data and with a `short` type this would cause an overflow
- Performance of `short` equal to the performance of `int` due to the "bitness" of processors. Modern CPUs take numbers of 32 or 64-bits, which fits both `int` and `short`. There *was* a performance benefit when running code on old 16-bit processors. Long time ago...

Comment: Since OP's talking about value ranges, he's clearly asking about [the other `read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28%29).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Agreed but the OP should certainly have clarified that himself.

Answer (score 1):

That's because read returns the number of bytes read, there is the following method defined in InputStream:

```
public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException
```

> Reads some number of bytes from the input stream and stores them into
>   the buffer array b. **The number of bytes actually read is returned as
>   an integer**. This method blocks until input data is available, end of
>   file is detected, or an exception is thrown.

The maximum length of an array is about Integer.MAX - 5, since you can do operations with arrays then the return type is an int.

Comment: Since OP's talking about value ranges, he's clearly asking about [the other `read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28%29).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight but as long as you can read from an array, and the array can hold as much as an integer, it is not possible to return a  short.

Comment: But that's irrelevant here, because he's talking about a `read` that takes no parameters, and returns a single `byte` as an `int`. OP wants to know why it isn't a `short`, because the byte would fit into `short` just as well, and also provide a `-1` for the `EOF`.

Answer (score 1):

Read method returns `int` which signifies number of bytes read from the file, its a design decision taken while writing the API, now lets ask same question other way around:

How many maximum bytes we can read ?

> •short: The short data type is a 16-bit signed two's complement
>   integer. It has a minimum value of -32,768 and a maximum value of
>   32,767 (inclusive). You can use a short to save memory in large
>   arrays, in situations where the memory savings actually matters.
>
> •int: By default, the int data type is a 32-bit signed two's
>   complement integer, which has a minimum value of -231 and a maximum
>   value of 231-1.

Assuming we will have enough memory to hold bytes, int serves a better candidate over short and hence the API design. However API leaves the decision to user to decide how many bytes to read based on resources available.

Also, `read` method calls native code and on the native language side, these primitive data types are mapped to the closest matching native language data type.

Cheers !!

Answer (score 1):

The real reason is that the abstract class that FileInputStream inherits from is also the base for InputStreams that are supposed to read *characters* in any encoding, and it has a method

```
public int read();
```

that is used in character reading streams to read a single character.

As we all know, a **char** is an unsigned integer type of 16-bit.

Hence, a **short** could not be used, because it only has 32k (or 15 bits worth) positive values, but we need 64k (or 16 bits worth) for characters.

And we need (-1) to signal end of file.

It is the same story with `Reader`s of all kinds and sorts.

Comment: The inheritance is indeed the underlying reason, but the method only has to return a 'byte' or a sentinel, not a 'char' and a sentinel, so the argument from 'char' doesn't apply. It applies to Readers.