# Processor usage when using byte and short data types in Java

Tags: java, variables, math, processor

I read the following in *Starting out with Java. from control structures through data structures - 3rd edition* by Tony Gaddis on page 67:

> When values of the byte or short data types are used in arithmetic expressions, they are temporarily converted to int values.

This is referring to Java.

**I was wondering if doing mathematical operations using byte or short data types, although they save memory, increases the processor usage due to the conversion to the int data type, as opposed to just using int data types.**

For example:

Does this:

```
byte x = 2;
byte y = 3;
int z = x + y;
```

use ***more*** of the processor than this:

```
int x = 2;
int y = 3;
int z = x + y;
```

I understand that the first example uses less memory. And I also understand that the difference in processor usage, if any, would be very slight.

Comment: Have you considered benchmarking this your self?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531235/in-java-is-it-more-efficient-to-use-byte-or-short-instead-of-int-and-float-inst

Comment: @bhspencer I did and my results were inconclusive. Not enough accuracy. Therefore I am looking for a theoretical approach to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do computation (like x+y), processor need to load both x and y in registers (depends on architecture, but at least on of x or y should be in registers). Registers have size of 32 or 64 bits (at least on platforms where Java can be used). So, this values are anyways are converted to 32(64) bit integer. It is done automatically and does not consume additional CPU resources. So computational speed will be the same.

Comment: I did a benchmark in milliseconds and this was confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, storing information as byte or byte array will add to the load on your processor if you need to perform computations.

Generally there is no reason to save your int's as byte's unless you are going to be storing so many of them for so long that they will fill up your available HEAP space. If you are just storing them for a few cycles to perform a computation then you probably don't need to store them as byte's as they will be removed by GC automatically once you are no longer using them.

Another option, if you are going to be using the same group on int's over and over again, and storing them for a long period of time, might be to create a pool of Integers. By doing this you can create a pool of say 1 million unique Integers in memory and simply save a pointer to that Integer in memory whenever you want to perform a computation with that particular int. This will probably end up saving more space than saving each individual int as a byte depending on your application...

Without knowing more about your particular application it is hard to recommend a particular course of action. Could you provide some more information?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is no particular application. I was just wondering about the theory behind it in general. I have been learning about primitive data types in university and just want to be as thorough in my understanding of them as possible, in case I actually need to employ byte or short someday.