# Why negative signed integer with bitwise AND 0xFF will result in positive signed integer?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit

My goal is to understand the two's complement.

`10000111` in signed integer equals to `-121`. However, if you bitwise AND it with `0xFF` in hexadecimal or `11111111` in decimal, it will equals to `135`.

In my view, this should not happen because the top byte `10000111` is identical to the result byte `10000111`

```
    10000111
AND 11111111
------------
    10000111 = 135.
```

My expected result is the value should not change, which is equals to `-121`.

My actual result is the value changes.

My guess is that, the `0xFF` is a `unsigned bit`. Therefore, the **signed** bit `1` on the top byte and **unsigned** bit `1` on the lower byte will result in unsigned bit `1`. But... that could not be right.

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class WebSocketWorkerThreadTest {
  @Test
  void SignedToUnsignedInteger() {
    byte signed = (byte) 0b10000111;
    // If java uses unsigned integer, it should be 135. however, java uses signed integer. Therefore, the outputs will be -121
    // 10000111
    // ^
    // the sign bit. If it exists then the value will be negative.
    Assertions.assertEquals(-121, signed);
    // 10000111
    // 11111111
    // --------
    // 10000111
    int unsigned = signed & 0xFF;
    Assertions.assertEquals(135, unsigned);
  }
}
```

Comment: `signed` is promoted to `int` when you apply the `&` operator. It's not `10000111 & 11111111`, it's `11111111111111111111111110000111 & 00000000000000000000000011111111`.

Comment: @AndyTurner ahh I see. In other words, before I apply the `&` operator, the byte signed value is `10000111` in binary. However, right before the operation, it gets converted to `32-bit` and then it's get AND-ing by the lower byte of `00000000000000000000000011111111`?

Comment: Java does not support signed vs unsigned for it's primitive types, as @user16320675 states. All values are signed, except for characters, which are always positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`signed` is promoted to `int` when you apply the `&` operator, because of *binary numeric promotion*.

It's not `10000111 & 11111111`, it's `11111111111111111111111110000111 & 00000000000000000000000011111111`, the value of which is `00000000000000000000000010000111` (still an int).

The MSB here is zero, hence it's positive.

If you cast it back to a byte, which would take just the 8 LSBs, that byte would be negative again.

Comment: this is correct, but fixable. OP should cast to byte.

Comment: @TreffnonX binary numeric promotion would cast it straight back to int. And `(int) (byte) 0xFF = -1`, so you'd be doing `(int) aByte & -1`, which is simply `(int) aByte`, so all you'd achieve by doing that would be doing is widening a byte to int.

Comment: `byte unsigned = (byte) (signed & 0xFF);` works perfectly well. It returns `-121` as expected

Comment: @TreffnonX Why cast back to a byte, then you're just back where you started.

Comment: Exactly. That is what OP expected. OP stated: "My expected result is the value should not change, which is equals to -121.". OP wants to apply a non-op, when applying an all-1-bit-value. Therefore he should treat all upper bits as redundant and just remove them after the op by casting to byte.

Comment: @AndyTurner does widening a byte to int will give a performance penalty?

Comment: @kidfrom vs what? The widening is unavoidable in Java.

Comment: @AndyTurner vs int. I am referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531235/in-java-is-it-more-efficient-to-use-byte-or-short-instead-of-int-and-float-inst). what do you think?

Comment: @kidfrom doing an operation can't be more performant than not. The operation can be avoided by using a wider data type, but that can't use less memory than a narrower data type. It's a design choice you have to make; but if by "performance penalty" you mean the speed difference, it's essentially zero.

Answer (score 0):

Java stores integers (, long and *byte*) in the two's complement. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

In this representation, any negative number begins with a bunch of 1-bits, because the value `10000... 0000` is the lowest representable value and the value `1111... 111` is -1.
For that reason, when you clip the leading 1-bits, you completely shift the number up into the positive range, because the new number does not start with a 1-bit anymore.

In your case, you use byte, but the value of your byte does not have the form you expect. It is an integer, when the `&` operation is applied, because you did not cast `0xFF` to byte. The easiest to fix this, is to cast the result of the `&` operation to byte, as suggested by another answer.